# Display the images as items in spinner

Tags: android

i am implemented to kids application i am implemented spinner in added array categeory list these are array text list now i am implement these text array list replace in drawable images in spinner how can implemented

```
personalinformation = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerCategory);
ArrayAdapter<?> adapterDefaultpersonal = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Animals.this,R.array.Animalinformation, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapterDefaultpersonal.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
personalinformation.setAdapter(adapterDefaultpersonal);
personalinformation.setSelection( getSharedPreferences("", 0).getInt("SpinnerSelection", 0));
personalinformation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View v,int position,long id)
{
if(position==0)
{
}});

this is the spinner code i am using array of text list these text replaced to drawable items in to spinner how can implemented some solution i am new in android
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want to have the spinner show icons instead of text.
Then you need to extend your ArrayAdapter to override the `getView()` to return an imageView instead.
Have a look at [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html) for more info.